# Equal card size on mobile resolution

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the size of the cards. On the Desktop side are ok, but on a lower resolution begin to be no longer equal. How should I proceed in this situation? I'm not an expert in css, I work on the backend but I would like in the future to have a correct solution how I could solve something like.

html

```
<div class="proditem">
    %PROMO%

    <div class="proditem_cover">
        <a href="%LINK%">%COVER%</a>
        %promo_period%
    </div>
    <h3 class="protitem_title">
        <a href="%LINK%">%TITLE%</a>
    </h3>

    <div class="protitem_price">
        %PRICE% eur %price_euro%
    </div>
    <div class="detalils"><a class="button1" href="%LINK%">Details</a></div>
</div>
```

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size:16px;}

.list_prod .proditem {
    height: auto;
    max-height: initial;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 40%;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 2px 16px;
    border: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 1rem;


.proditem img {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    max-width: 10vw;
    max-height: 10vw;
    /* object-fit: cover; */
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayZfZ.png)

As far as I can see, they decrease in size because they don't have the same information, depending on the text and image if they're not equal. How can I make them equal regardless of the information they have?

Comment: hello. show more code + your html, pls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to create wrapper class like :

```
<div style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; justify-content:flex-start;" class="wrapper"> 
 <div style="width:50%; height:100%; " class="content"> <div/>
 <div style="width:50%; height:100%; class="content"> <div/>
<div/>
```

This just a simple example to give you a some styling or aligning tricks. Try and write me if its not-proper code for you.

Comment: I would not like to use style functions in divs, I would actually like to solve in that css if I could and there is a concrete solution

Comment: If you share more codes, maybe we can solve your problem with just CSS styling.